# 30 seconds response time just in GET request, why?

Tags: php, wordpress, get, rss

I was trying to add some RSS feeds on my Wordpress site. The plug-in is called WP RSS Multi-importer, and it is based on [SimplePie](http://www.simplepie.org/demo/).

I've tested [my feed url](http://www.paho.org/arg/index.php?format=feed&type=rss) in the SimplePie demo website and it works. Very fast.

However, my GET request to the page that contains the feed takes about 30 seconds! and even fails sometimes. It doesn't happen on the other pages.
If you don't mind, I attached the website page where I'm testing it out [here](http://farmaciadelpueblo.sytes.net:1234/fdp/temas-de-salud/).

EDIT: I forgot to say that the website is currently hosted in my computer running in WAMP.

Comment: This is your problem. EDIT: I forgot to say that the website is currently hosted in my computer running in WAMP.

Comment: So that's the problem? Everything else works fine in WAMP, I though it was strange.

Comment: i am not completely sure., but when i tried accesing your site, it took forever and didnt load either. try hosting your files on some small vps.

Comment: i've changed it! please try here: farmaciadelpueblo.sytes.net/fdp/temas-de-salud

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP/Cpanel than,

add `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of `wp-config.php`.

This will help you to set `The maximum execution time`.

`0` means **Unlimited**, If you want to specify your custom timeout, that add numbers in seconds, `eg:- set_time_limit(60); means 60seconds`.

[More Information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)..

Comment: I forgot to say that my website is currently hosted in my WAMP, and I've put it online.

The problem is that I don't want to extend the excution time limit. I want to load it quickly. I don't know why it is so slow. It works fine in the SimplePie demo page.